# sql if statements error

Tags: sql

I dont know what's the error in this sql code

```
  IF ((SELECT type FROM filter )=2 )


 SELECT  user.id,user.name,user.img as img1

   ELSE IF ((SELECT type FROM filter )=1 ) 

SELECT  feed.id as centerid,feed.img as img2`
```

Comment: What isn't working properly? You need to post an error log or explain what goes wrong

Comment: That's completely invalid SQL syntax.

Comment: Are you creating a stored procedure? or just a sql query?  What's the error? what are you expecting (result)?

Comment: How is this related to Android?!!!!

Comment: am using the type row as a categories, if type =1 select from the comments table ,if type = 2 select from the rating table

Answer (score 0):

No-one else has answered, so I'll jump in... Your problem is that you're trying to write SQL the way you would write a routine in a programming language such as C, PHP, Java, etc, but SQL doesn't work like that - it's a declarative language, which means that you tell it **what you want, not how to do it**.

In the example in your question you seem to be trying to return different column sets depending on a value, but AFAIK that isn't possible. What I'd do instead is return all the columns, and then in your application just use the ones you want.

That gives you something like this:

```
SELECT [column names] FROM [table name]
WHERE [column name] in (1, 2);
```

However, what you really need to do is buy a good book on SQL and learn how to write it properly. :-)